# How to tell difference between standard field and custom field with same name?

Tags: custom-field, account, fields

[image]

Editing a Workflow Rule Criteria and there is a custom field and a standard field with the same name. (Bad form I know, I didn't make it)

How can I tell them apart? Which are listed first Standard Fields, or Custom fields? Or is there a different sort order?

I could rename one of them, but I don't want to break existing formulas, workflows etc.

Comment: You can check the metadata of the workflow after creation and make sure the API name is correct

Comment: Awesome. How do I check the metadata? Sorry rookie q?

Comment: @JoshuaDance You can just change the label of the field and dont touch api name .Changing label should not break anything

Comment: Thanks! It warned me about merge templates, but I can just change it back.

Comment: You can download the metadata via force.com IDE, there full documentation on setting this up. Definitely changing the label is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can change Field Labels (don't change the API Name) and it only affects merge templates. So I just changed the Field Label of the Custom one to be different from the standard field label, so I could tell them apart.

One note, if you use the Analytics API or otherwise interprets SFDC Report outputs, @crop1645 reports that if Description was one of the fields used, changing the label will break those integrations.

Amr mentioned that you can check the metadata of the workflow, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks to Mohith for the help.

Comment: If you use any product that exploits the Analytics API or otherwise interprets SFDC Report output (like Conga Composer), changing the label will break those integrations if `Description` was one of the fields used.

Answer (score 1):

One way to differentiate is not to keep the same labels as that of the Standard fields .Only changing labels will not affect anything than merge fields in email templates and other minor places .If there are managed app exchange products please talk to your provider to see if it does have any impact on integration's.